# oop java method to increment number sequentially

Tags: java, oop, sequence

Im having an issue where I have to create a method in java to get a ticket number which every time it is called it generates a number sequentially.

this is what I have so far regarding the ticket method

```
public class Ticket
{
    public static final String PREFIX = "CAR";
    public static int number = 1000;

    //instance variables
    private String ticketNumber;

public Ticket(){
         ticketNumber = generateTicketNumber();
        }
public String getTicketNumber(){
        return ticketNumber;
    }

private String generateTicketNumber(){
        number = number++;
        ticketNumber = PREFIX +number;
        return ticketNumber;
    }
```

I'm told to use a static variable (which i have) to create and hold a counter to generate part of the ticket number, increment the static variable and assign it combined with the string prefix to the field ticketNumber. When i create an object it does not increment to CAR1001, it just goes CAR1000, am I to try a while loop for this?

Comment: You should not use an expression like x = x++. The reason for this is that a trailing ++ is the post-increment operator. First, x's value is saved. Then x is incremented. Then x is assigned the saved value of the original x. You probably should have just used number++ without the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

`number = number++;` is not evaluated how you think. What this actually does is that the right-hand side increments `number`, but `number++` is also an expression whose value is the *old* value of `number`, before the increment is done. Then because of the `number = ...` assignment, that old value is assigned to `number` on the left-hand side, undoing the increment.

So you should just write `number++;` instead, which simply increments the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I think you've over complicated this. All you need is `PREFIX` and `number`. Concatenate `PREFIX` with `number` and increment `number`. That can be done in one step like,

```
public class Ticket {
    private static final String PREFIX = "CAR";
    private static int number = 1000;

    public String getTicketNumber() {
        return PREFIX + number++;
    }
}
```

Or, perhaps a little easier to read,

```
public String getTicketNumber() {
    try {
        return PREFIX + number;
    } finally {
        number++;
    }
}
```